Finding a Closed Form Expression for a Distribution Defined by an Integral Involving Sine and Bessel Functions
I am seeking a closed form expression for the following distribution:
$$ D(t,x) = \int_0^\infty d\omega\, \omega^2 \sin(\omega t) J_0(\omega x), $$
where $J_0(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero.
This distribution produces well-defined results when integrated against test functions of $t$ and $x$ that decay sufficiently fast at infinity. For example, using Gaussian test functions, the integrals
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\, D(t,x) e^{-(t-t_0)^2} = \int_0^\infty d\omega \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\, \omega^2 \sin(\omega t) J_0(\omega x) e^{-(t-t_0)^2}, $$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, D(t,x) e^{-(x-x_0)^2} = \int_0^\infty d\omega \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, \omega^2 \sin(\omega t) J_0(\omega x) e^{-(x-x_0)^2}, $$
are well-defined for any real numbers $t_0$ and $x_0$. These double integrals converge as long as the integral over $\omega$ is performed last, after integrating over $t$ or $x$.
The closest I have come to a closed form involves recognizing that $D(t,x)$ can be expressed as the second partial derivative with respect to $t$ of another distribution,
$$ C(t,x) = -\int_0^\infty d\omega\, \sin(\omega t) J_0(\omega x), \quad D(t,x) = \partial_t^2 C(t,x). $$
The distribution $C(t,x)$ has the following closed form:
$$ C(t,x) = -\frac{\text{sgn}(t)\Theta(t^2 - x^2)}{\sqrt{t^2 - x^2}}, $$
where $\text{sgn}(t)$ is the sign function and $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function.
However, when attempting to compute $\partial_t^2 C(t,x)$ to find a closed form for $D(t,x)$, I encounter difficulties:
$$ \partial_t^2 C(t,x) = \frac{\text{sgn}(t)\Theta(t^2 - x^2) (2t^2 + x^2)}{(t^2 - x^2)^{5/2}}, \quad \text{for } |t| \neq |x|. $$
This expression for $D(t,x)$ is valid for test functions that decay to zero quickly enough when $|t|$ approaches $|x|$, but it gives divergent results when integrated against Gaussian test functions or, in general, against any other test functions that do not approach zero as $|t|$ approaches $|x|$. On the other hand, $D(t,x)$ is well-defined through its integral form even for Gaussian test functions, so this closed form expression does not fully capture the distribution $D(t,x)$.
Is there a modification to this closed form expression around $|t| = |x|$ that provides a valid expression for $D(t,x)$ for any test functions that decay sufficiently fast at infinity?

Mathematica and WolframAlpha give the result
$$D(t,x)=\mathcal{M}_{\omega}[\sin(\omega t)\, J_0(\omega x)](3)=\int_0^{\infty} \sin(\omega t)\, J_0(\omega x)\, \omega^{3-1} \, d\omega\\=-\frac{4 \sqrt{\pi}}{x^3}\, G_{2,2}^{0,2}\left(\frac{t^2}{x^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} \\
 0,\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\\=-\frac{\left(4 \sqrt{\pi}\right)}{x^3} \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & \left| \frac{t^2}{x^2}\right| <1 \\
 \frac{2 t^2+x^2}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{t^2}{x^2}-1\right)^{5/2} x^2} & \left| \frac{t^2}{x^2}\right| >1 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)\tag{1}$$
when evaluating the integral as the Mellin transform $\mathcal{M}_{\omega}[\sin(\omega t)\, J_0(\omega x)](s)$ at $s=3$ where $G$ is the Meijer G-Function and where the expansion of the Meijer G-Function in formula (1) above was provided by Mathematica.

Mathematica gives the same result via the Hankel transform
$$D(t,x)=\mathcal{H}_{\omega}[\omega \sin(t \omega)](x)=\int_0^{\infty} \omega\, \sin(\omega t)\, \omega\, J_0(\omega x) \, d\omega\\=-\frac{4 \sqrt{\pi}}{x^3}\, G_{2,2}^{0,2}\left(\frac{t^2}{x^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} \\
 0,\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\tag{2}$$
of order zero.

Figure (1) below illustrates for $x_0>0$, $D(t,x_0)$ is a continuous function of $t$ at $t=0$ with $D(0,x_0)=0$ and
$$\underset{t\to (-x_0)^-}{\text{lim}} D(t,x_0)=\underset{t\to x_0^+}{\text{lim}} D(t,x_0)=-\infty\tag{3}$$
$$\underset{t\to (-x_0)^+}{\text{lim}} D(t,x_0)=\underset{t\to x_0^-}{\text{lim}} D(t,x_0)=0\tag{4}.$$


Figure (1): Illustration of $D(t,1)$ and $D(t,2)$ in blue and orange

Figure (2) below illustrates for $t_0>0$, $D(t_0,x)$ is a discontinuous function of $x$ at $x=0$ and
$$\underset{x\to (-t_0)^+}{\text{lim}} D(t_0,x)=\infty\tag{5}$$
$$\underset{x\to t_0^-}{\text{lim}} D(t_0,x)=-\infty\tag{6}$$
$$\underset{x\to (-t_0)^-}{\text{lim}}D(t_0,x)=\underset{x\to t_0^+}{\text{lim}} D(t_0,x)=0\tag{7}.$$


Figure (2): Illustration of $D(1,x)$ and $D(2,x)$ in blue and orange

Thank you for your answer, I did not know this method. This method gives a similar result to the procedure I gave in the question, where I provided an expression from computing $\partial_t^2 C(t,x)$. The only difference is that the $sgn(t)$ is not appearing when using the Mellin transform.
Nonetheless, I am most interested in what occurs when $|t/x|=1$. Is there closed form for the distribution that includes this case?

@AdamTeixidóBonfill I updated my answer above to provide some clarification as to why $D(t,x)$ is undefined for this case.
